# React import component names clashing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

Unsure how to solve clash between two import components in ReactJS, i.e.:

```
import Select from './FormsUI/Select';
import Select from 'react-select';
```

Based on the above, is it possible to use a difference name to access **react-select** library as I'm using the first **Select** from `./FormsUI/Select` numerous times in my App?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're importing the *default* export from each of those modules, which means you control the local name. So you could do:

```
import FormsUISelect from './FormsUI/Select';
import ReactSelect from 'react-select';
```

**If** they were named exports (they aren't in your question), you could still control the local name using `as`:

```
import { Select as FormsUISelect } from './FormsUI/Select';
import { Select as ReactSelect } from 'react-select';
```

Comment: (FWIW, I go into `import` and `export` extensively in Chapter 13 of my recent book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*, including renaming. Links in my profile if you're interested.)

Comment: Is it possible to only do the `{ Select as ReactSelect }` only and not do the `as` at all on the first import, i.e. just leave it as `import Select from './FormsUI/Select';` ?

Comment: @tonyfat - Yup, you only need to rename one of them. I just did both for ... clarity? (Don't think I succeeded there. :-D ) These names are purely local to your module, so you can use any names you want.

Answer (score 0):

Import one of them with alias

`import * as UISelect from './FormsUI/Select`

Comment: That would work, yes, but there's no reason to import everything from the module for this.

Comment: Also worth noting that to use the select they'd need to do `<UISelect.Select ... />`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';
```

you can use `AsyncSelect` instead of select if select conflects with another select component or library.

Answer (score 0):

You can import react-select like this:

```
import { default as ReactSelect} from 'react-select';
```